# правила RewriteCond и проверка на HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess

есть такие правила:

## 1

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/%filename1%)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(%filename2%)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /seo/%1 [L,QSA]
```

## 2 http part

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(%filename3%)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(%filename4%)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /seo/http/%1 [L,QSA]
```

## 3 https part

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO} https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(%filename5%)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(%filename6%)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /seo/https/%1 [L,QSA]
```

Вопрос:
1) Можно ли объединить в один RewriteRule ?
2) Правильно ли сделана проверка на https протокол ?